# Remove the first block of text that match a regex with sed

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have a text like this

```
# This configuration was generated by
# `rubocop --auto-gen-config`

# Offense count: 1
# Configuration parameters: Include.
# Include: **/Gemfile, **/gems.rb
Bundler/DuplicatedGem:
  Exclude:
    - 'Gemfile'

# Offense count: 24
# Cop supports --auto-correct.
# Configuration parameters: Include, TreatCommentsAsGroupSeparators.
# Include: **/Gemfile, **/gems.rb
Bundler/OrderedGems:
  Exclude:
    - 'Gemfile'

# Offense count: 1
# Cop supports --auto-correct.
Layout/MultilineBlockLayout:
  Exclude:
    - 'test/unit/github_fetcher/issue_comments_test.rb'

# Offense count: 1
# Cop supports --auto-correct.
# Configuration parameters: EnforcedStyle, SupportedStyles.
# SupportedStyles: symmetrical, new_line, same_line
Layout/MultilineHashBraceLayout:
  Exclude:
    - 'config/environments/production.rb'
```

And I'm looking to remove only the first block of text that start with `Offense count`. I have [a working regex](http://regexr.com/3ghkv) : `/^# Offense([\s\S]+?)\n\n/m`

If I use with sed I have and error:

```
$ sed -e '/^# Offense([\s\S]+?)\n\n\/d' .rubocop_todo.yml
sed: 1: "/^# Offense([\s\S]+?)\n ...": unterminated regular expression
```

If I had empty string as first param it does nothing:

```
$ sed -e '' '/^# Offense([\s\S]+?)\n\n\/d' .rubocop_todo.yml
```

Why is it failing? What can I do?

I'm on osx with `awk version 20070501` or `GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.5, GNU MP 6.1.2)`

Comment: sed works line by line and doesn't have non-greedy quantifiers (nor `\s` character class). In other words, your "working" regex is useless, you have to find an other approach. Start reading more about sed and what you can do with labels and with the pattern space. Read also about BRE and ERE (the two regex flavours available in sed). But in my opinion, sed isn't the good tool to do that, try with awk or perl.

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna take a look at awk

Comment: With awk or perl you can easily read your file by blocks if you define the record separator as `\n\n`. Then, all you have to do is to check if the current block starts with " Offense".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n"}!/^# Offense/||a++' file
```

details:

```
BEGIN {             # before starting to read the records
    RS=ORS="\n\n"   # define the record separator(RS) and the output record
                    # separator(ORS) 
}

# condition: when it's true, the record is printed
!/^# Offense/ # doesn't start with "# Offense"
||            # OR
a++           # "a" is true ( at the first block that starts with "# Offense", "a"
              # isn't defined and evaluated as false, then it is incremented and
              # evaluated as true for the next blocks.)
```

Comment: For the moment the command doesn't remove the first block but add empty line after each line.

Comment: @Mio: that's strange, I tested it with your string and it works well.

Comment: I'm on osx with `awk version 20070501` :/

Comment: Elegant logic.  Works fine for me.

Comment: @Mio: do you have the same result if you use switches instead of `BEGIN`: `awk -v RS="\n\n" -v ORS="\n\n" '!/^# Offense/||a++' file`?

Comment: Both works. I was only not piping properly in my script. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It seems that 2 new lines are added at the end of the output.

Comment: @SLePort: awk adds by default the record separator after the last record. With Gnu awk you can prevent it using RT: `awk -v RS="\n\n" '!/^# Offense/||a++{printf "%s%s",$0,RT}' file`. Without Gnu awk you can display the RS before each records except for the first one: `awk -v RS="\n\n" '!/^# Offense/||a++{printf "%s%s",(NR>1)?RS:"",$0}' file`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an `awk` expression that will print everything except the first block that starts with `# Offense` and ends with a blank line:

```
awk '/# Offense/ {n++}  n!=1 {print}  n&&/^$/ {n++}' file
```

Breakdown:

- We have three expressions here, each of the form: `condition { command }`. Condition can a complex (logical) expression composed of a regex matching the current line, variable test, etc.
- `n` is a block counter, incremented on start and end of the block. Initially, `n=0`.
- `/# Offense/ {n++}` - after we match the first `# Offense`, we increase it to`n=1`
- `n && /^$/ {n++}` - and after that block finishes (we match the blank link, but only after the first block detected, `n>0`), we increase it again to `n=2`.
- `n != 1 {print}` - in the meantime, while we're outside of the first block, we print each line, verbatim.

Comment: Yes, we don't want to increase `n` before the first block.

Comment: in this case write `/^$/ && n++`. n is tested and incremented only if `/^$/` succeeds.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, that actually won't work, because `n` must not be incremented on any blank line match, but only *after* the start of the first block.

Answer (score 1):

Sed says "unterminated regular expression" because the last slash has a backslash in front of it: `\/` will escape this final slash and render the string invalid as a regex.

I think you can do it in this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -0pe 's/# Offense.*?\n\n//s' test.yml
```

Where: `-0` set the record separator to null, effectively read the whole thing in one string, `-p` prints the result (if you want to replace it in-place, add `-i`, i.e. `perl -i -0pe ...`), and `-e` treat the next string as a regex. The `*?` makes this non-greedy so only the first section will be matched. And the `/s` modifier will make the dot match newlines as well.

Output:

```
# This configuration was generated by

# Offense count: 24
# Cop supports --auto-correct.
# Configuration parameters: Include, TreatCommentsAsGroupSeparators.
# Include: **/Gemfile, **/gems.rb
Bundler/OrderedGems:
  Exclude:
    - 'Gemfile'
```